# JSPM - Are there any advantages/disadvantages in including client side library files using import vs using the script tag?

Tags: javascript, import, aurelia, jspm

I'm starting to use JSPM in my Aurelia web projects and I want to know if there are any consequences or advantages in using the `import "<client side library>"` ?

I've seen code like so for client side libraries inside JS classes :

```
import "jquery";
import "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!"
import "bootstrap";

export class App {
    constructor {

    }
}
```

**Question:** What is the difference/advantages/disadvantages between importing it this way as oppose to the traditional include of `<script>` and `<link>` tags in the `.html` file?

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" src="<bootstrap path>/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="<bootstrap path>/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My trial and error shows me that by using `import` in a particular class/js file, it limits the libraries to that particular view file as oppose to being globally available.

Ultimately when you go to build these project for production, don't these libraries need to exists in the index.html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My opinion is: you should use the `import` keyword, and here is why:

- **A matter of style**: it's ES6-style, and Aurelia kinda obliges you to use it
- **Readability** that matters: other developers would expect you to use `import`, so it might confuse them
- Again, `import` takes care of loading that, so if you just add a script tag, you might add some `import` and then some function might be redeclared.
- **Beauty**: I don't think it's very pretty to have 100 `<script>` tags in your code
- **Bundling for production**. Are you going to concat and uglify all that with Grunt or Gulp? If so, that's extra work, because in the default config it comes out of the box. If no... well, no, you should do that
- **[Rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup)**. And here comes the sweetest part.

> JSPM is awesome! It's a little different to this project though – it
>   combines a repository with a package manager and a client-side module
>   loader, as opposed to simply bundling modules. JSPM allows you to use
>   any module format and even develop without a build step, so it's a
>   great choice for creating applications. Rollup generates smaller
>   bundles that don't use the complex SystemJS format, and so is a better
>   choice for creating libraries. **A future version of JSPM may use Rollup
>   internally, so you'll get the best of both worlds**.

Rollup is another **pro** for using `import`. What it does is ripping the libraries you use and taking the minimal amount of code you need, so if you need only some stuff from, let's say, jQuery, you won't need to make your visitors download 50KB (or how much is it now?).

You can read more about Rollup [here](https://github.com/rollup/rollup#a-next-generation-es6-module-bundler).

Comment: Thanks that actually made a lot of sense, thanks for the explanation. I'm still a bit confused about the bundling and beauty part. In my current workflow I uglify + concat everything into 1 lib.css file 1 app.css and 1 lib.js + 1 app.js. So there will be 4 files only in total in Index. I'll have a look at Rollup it looks promising.

Comment: @TheLazyChap maybe you'll find this article on bundling interesting http://blog.durandal.io/2015/06/23/bundling-an-aurelia-application/

Comment: Don't forget that import takes care of dependencies. If you code import a module that depends on other module, that depends on other module, and other and other, all dependencies are loaded in the correct other, by the time the module is constructed it dependency is in memory. Also the bundle process of aurelia rip of the code you don't use and bundle the modules and dependency's you use to runtime performance

Comment: This is also great for huge projects, instead of load all in memory you load on demand

Comment: jspm production workflows https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/production-workflows.md was useful for me to understand the different options available.