# What is best practice for making a library like lodash globally available in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I want to be able to use lodash ( _ ) in a convenient way, but am looking for the best 'Aurealia' way to do so. I can see a few options:

- Use a downloaded copy or CDN and simply include a `<script>` tag
  reference in index.html
- Install via `npm` or `jspm` (which??) and
  then either:

  - `import` it in every module, which seems tedious
  - use one of Aurelia's `feature` or `plugin` or `globalResources` or `someother???` features to load it and make universally available.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327133/jspm-are-there-any-advantages-disadvantages-in-including-client-side-library-f) seems to indicate in a generic way that using `import` is best, but I'm stumped as to how.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These are my opinions- take with a grain of salt:

## Aurelia Purist

The Aurelia Purist doesn't use lodash, instead opting to write modern javascript using the [new array methods](http://www.2ality.com/2014/05/es6-array-methods.html) that ship with ES6. Sometimes the Aurelia purist consults [you might not need underscore](https://www.reindex.io/blog/you-might-not-need-underscore/) when he or she is in doubt.  Other times the Aurelia purist consults [you might not need jquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

## Aurelia Pragmatist

The Aurelia Pragmatist recognizes that Aurelia is just one tool in his or her toolbelt. The Aurelia framework, much like lodash and jQuery, help the Aurelia Pragmatist *ship quality software* that *delights users*. The Aurelia Pragmatist recognizes that there is more than one way to bake a cake and chooses to use the tools he or she is most effective with.

## Answering the question...

You won't find anything in Aurelia that makes `_` universally available with no strings attached.  You can certainly make it a classic global OR you could install it with jspm and import it into each module as-needed.  There's no middle ground that saves you from importing it AND saves you from feeling bad about using a global.

IMHO it's not the end of the world if your stuff has deps on the lodash global. It's a preference thing, your project certainly won't fail if you pick one or the other.

Answer (score 10):

Great answer from Jeremy (as always). I'll just add up to that...

Try to use ES6 array methods wherever you can (Aurelia Purist standpoint). If you need some thing that cannot be replicated with native ECMAScript, or you really prefer to use `lodash`, install it using `jspm`:

```
jspm install lodash
```

`lodash` is an alias for `npm:lodash` defined in `jspm` registry. `jspm` will install `lodash` from `npm`'s registry but will manage it itself - inside `jspm_packages` and with `system.js` module loader.

To use `_` from your module, do an import:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

After that, you can use `_` in your module code, like you would expected:

```
let result = _.map(...);
```

---

Edit: Thanks @VolkerRose for suggestion.

### `lodash` modules with full installation

It's also possible to import only the functionality you need from `lodash`. If you need `map` function only, this is what you would use within your modules:

```
import map from 'lodash/map';
// ...
let result = map(...);
```

When `lodash/map` is required, `jspm` will find a `lodash` module folder (`jspm_packages/npm/lodash@4.3.0` if version `4.3.0` is installed) and use the rest of the `from` value to search within that folder. In this case, all `lodash` modules/files are in the root folder - so `map.js` module is used. If there were any subfolders involved, you would need to use something like  `import map from 'lodash/some/sub/folder/map'`).

### `lodash` modules with standalone installation

As @VolkerRose [said in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372195/what-is-best-practice-for-making-a-library-like-lodash-globally-available-in-aur/35373892?noredirect=1#comment58508409_35373892), `lodash` is [modularized](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized) and you can install just the modules you need.

```
jspm install npm:lodash.map
```

This will install `lodash`'s map module. Note that we need `npm:` prefix this time, since `jspm` doesn't have aliases for standalone `lodash` modules.

The `lodash.map` module can now be used similar as above:

```
import map from 'lodash.map';
// ...
let result = map(...);
```

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate your answer as lodash modules are also available as standalone versions? See https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized.
So there are some ways to directly use the `map` module, like `var map = require('lodash.map');` or `var map = require('lodash/map')` (if you installed the full lodash version).

Comment: @VolkerRose Thanks for suggestion, I have expanded the answer.

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic likewise, nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

you can install the lodash with jspm

```
jspm install lodash
```

and then to consume it globally in you app using a global import as follow:

```
import 'lodash';
```

example:
in your main file, it will load the lib globally in the window context.

```
// importing lodash as global resource
import 'lodash';     

import 'bootstrap';

import {Aurelia, LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ConsoleAppender} from 'aurelia-logging-console';
import {authConfig} from './config/auth-config';

LogManager.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender());
LogManager.setLevel(LogManager.logLevel.debug);

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .defaultBindingLanguage()
        .defaultResources()
        .history()
        .router()
        .eventAggregator();

    aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```